# Где лучше хранить данные, в базе данных или в массиве?

Tags: mysql

Добрый вечер!

Подскажите, где лучше хранить данные о товаре (500 - 1000 наименований). В базе или достаточно файла с массивом?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Однозначно - база данных.
Из основных плюсов: многопоточность, нет необходимости загружать весь файл для работы с базой, будущие обновления базы без необходимости вносить данные в массив и записывать его в файл, что тоже затратно, индексы.